# SendGrid misconfiguration on Google Cloud (535 Authentication failed)

Tags: google-compute-engine, sendgrid

So I've installed SendGrid on GoogleCE with Centos base following the documented instruction from Google:

[https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid#before-you-begin][1]

Using the test from the command line (various accounts):

```
echo 'MESSAGE' | mail -s 'SUBJECT' GJ******@gmail.com
```

the /var/log/maillog says with several lines of 50 or so attempts in 1 second:

```
postfix/error[32324]: A293210062D7: to=<GJ********@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=145998, delays=145997/1.2/0/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.sendgrid.net[167.89.115.53] said: 535 Authentication failed: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked)
```

And the message is queued up and retried every few hours.   Now, messing around, I could change the port setting from 2525 to one of the regular ports that isn't blocked by google and the email gets bounced right away to the user account in the mail test message.

I made sure to use the api key generated, the SendGrid system say no attempt have been made or bounced or whatever.

There were other errors in the maillog, actually as it tries every second, pages of them, but I change the perms in that directory so no longer, but maybe gives a clue to how it's misconfigured?

```
Oct 31 19:04:14 beadc postfix/pickup[15119]: fatal: chdir("/var/spool/postfix"): Permission denied
Oct 31 19:04:15 beadc postfix/master[1264]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/qmgr pid 15118 exit status 1
Oct 31 19:04:15 beadc postfix/master[1264]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/qmgr: bad command startup -- throttling
Oct 31 19:04:15 beadc postfix/master[1264]: warning: process /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup pid 15119 exit status 1
Oct 31 19:04:15 beadc postfix/master[1264]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/pickup: bad command startup -- throttling
```

The only info I can find searching about the error is that it means a SendGrid misconfiguration.

Any ideas as to what the misconfiguration might be?

Answer (score 0):

I've determined the 535 error was a port/firewall issue.  Which means that the 550 error I had on the other port still exists.

Check your firewall settings on 535

[https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/][1]